# Handling incoming call in android

Tags: android

In my app i want to detect incoming call and i want to hide default incoming call layout with my custom layout,far now i have managed to get the state of incoming call but i'm not able to hide the default incoming call screen...below is my code and my android manifest file...any help will be appreciated..

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("DEBUG", "on recive called");
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
    {
        abortBroadcast();
        Log.d("MPR", "Its Ringing [" + number + "]");
        //start activity
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.ezest.callerid", "com.ezest.callerid.CustomCallActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
    {
        Log.d("MPR", "Its Idle");
    }
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state))
    {
        Log.d("MPR", "Its OffHook");
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <receiver android:name="MYPhoneStateListener">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".CallerIDActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="CustomCallActivity">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: As far as I know you will not able able to hide the system incall screen when using the SDK.

Comment: @wojci..but i have seen apps on market with this functionality..

Comment: Do you know if they are using reflection and trying to access internal parts of the telephony framework?

Answer (score 0):

when defined action is happened android operating system send broadcast to all defined broadcastreceiver for this action. it does this job according to priority order. I can see you have done it. copy that code where you want to cancel broadcast.

```
abortBroadcast()
```

Android operating system will stop broadcasting to other broadcastreceivers

Comment: @bmavus...thanks..but still  its showing the default screen...is there anything i'm missing??

Comment: I see that you have written abortBroadcast() in your if statement. write it end of the if stataments(write it as last code line of onReceive method)

Comment: @bmavus..this is the exception i'm getting..java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast...

Comment: The incoming call broadcast is non-ordered, so you are unable to abort the broadcast from your receiver.  I'm still not sure how to replace this screen, though it appears [other apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.perracolabs.tccp) are able to do it